# how to make an ajax call from cordova (it tried to load a file as far as I can see)

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

I need to make an ajax call:

```
call_server("192.168.1.102/proj04/get_all_food?extent=....", "GET"...).
```

(this is my higher order function btw; it worked before from the browser. Ofcourse, I didnt have 192.168.1.102 there cause it was my local machine)

The answer comes back:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   
file:///android_asset/www/192.168.1.102/proj04/get_all_food?extent=dessert
```

It tried to load a file from what I can tell. Also, the url is totally wrong.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost protocol, so that ajax will auto get current path is: file:///android_asset/www/ + url

```
call_server("http://192.168.1.102/proj04/get_all_food?extent=....", "GET"...)
```